# Regarding alcohol content medicines

Tags: fiqh, alcohol, medical

[image]
Can i continue using this medicine??
Is it permissible to use this medicine in islam?

Comment: No one to rply..?

Answer (score 2):

(Due to firewall I'm not able to watch pictures). So my answer is on the question whether one can take a medicine containing alcohol or not:
Assuming there's no medical product (or treatment) that doesn't contain alcohol and may have the same healing effect on you, you may use a medical product containing alcohol, else it is certainly forbidden.

- > The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Allah has sent down both the disease and the cure, and He has appointed a cure for every disease, so treat yourselves medically, but use nothing unlawful.  ([Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/20))
- > Wa'il al-Hadrami reported that Tariq b. Suwaid a-Ju'fi asked Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) about liquor. He forbade (its use) and he expressed hatred that it should be prepared. He (Tariq) said:
  >   I prepare it as a medicine, whereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: It is no medicine, but an ailment. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/15))

As alcohol is haram and one may only use something prohibited in case of necessity: necessity means one has no other option to do so without harming oneself or one would die if one doesn't use it!

On islamqa they hold the opinion that using medicine that contains a small amount of alcohol is allowed (5%<) -on a SHi'a site I've met a boundary of 2%-, but physicians should avoid medicine containing alcohol (See -only in Arabic- [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/ar/146013)), but mixing a medicine with alcohol on the other site is considered as haram (See for example [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/40530)).

See also this fatwas on [aboutislam.net](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/health-science/medicine-containing-alcohol-can-take/) (which seems to hold the same opinion as islamqa) and [islamweb.net](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=263212) (which seems to hold a rather refusing position).

Answer (score -4):

Religions and cultures that prohibit the consumption of alcohol do so because of the intoxicating nature of it when consumed in excess, and a lot of people really shouldn't drink alcohol. Trivial amounts that would have no intoxicating  effect. Learn [Quran Transilations](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/1/1/supplication-to-allah-for-guidance-taught-by-allah-himself) in-depth and understand Quran, u will get all answers there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (see [answer]).